# Datepicker for dynamically created controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, dynamic, datepicker

I have a page with a number of dynamic controls.

For some of the dynamically created textboxes, I'd like to add calendar control using jQuery ([Keith Wood](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html))

Normally, if the textbox controls are not dynamic, I would have the following javascript function to call on the calendar popup for the txtBoxDate textbox:

```
  $(function () {
     $('#<%=txtBoxDate.ClientID%>').datepick({ dateFormat: 'dd MM yyyy' });
  });
```

Since I don't now the IDs of my dynamically created textboxes, how do I call on the jQuery calendar function?

Any ideas?

Much appreciated!

EIDT: I create the controls as follows with some loop (to create multiple):

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow();
TableCell td1 = new TableCell();
TableCell td2 = new TableCell();

TextBox txtValue = new TextBox();
txtValue.Width = 250;
txtValue.ID = "textbox_" + dt.Rows[j][2].ToString();
```

Comment: Can you show the code for how you're creating the inputs?

Comment: Dynamically creating the textboxes? Sure I'll edit my question now.

Comment: updated, thanks tymeJV!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a css Class name to your editor that hold the Calendar and attach the datepicker base on that, eg:

```
TextBox txtValue = new TextBox();
        txtValue.Width = 250;
        txtValue.CssClass = "TheDateTimePicker";
```

and on script:

```
$(function () {
  $('.TheDateTimePicker').datepick({ dateFormat: 'dd MM yyyy' });
});
```

You can use the same css class name for all the editors that keep this date control, without change anything else. This `$('.TheDateTimePicker')` selector will apply the "datepick" to all controls that have that css class.