# Datepicker not appearing after adding rows to editable gridview

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, datepicker

I have an editable Gridview with columns as below:

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="160" CssClass="DateTimePicker" ></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amt $">
        <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Width="160"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <FooterTemplate>
         <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add Stage" onclick="ButtonAdd_Click" />
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
```

As you can see, this gridview as a button at the bottom which allows user to add rows to the gridview.

I want to have a calendar pop up for my Date column so I used jQuery ([Keith Wood](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html)) and call on the JS function like this:

```
    $(function () {

                $('.DateTimePicker').datepick({ dateFormat: 'dd MM yyyy' });
            });
```

In my gridview, the first time when I click on the Date textbox (on first row), the calendar pops up. However, once I add a row to the gridview, the calendar function no longer appears.

This is the way I add a new row to gridview from code-behind:

```
    private void AddNewRowToGrid()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;

        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    //extract the TextBox values
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                    TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");


                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                    drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;

                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column1"] = box1.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column2"] = box2.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column3"] = box3.Text;

                    rowIndex++;
                }
                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

                Gridview1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                Gridview1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("ViewState is null");
        }

        //Set Previous Data on Postbacks
        SetPreviousData();
    }
```

Any ideas why my calendar does not pop up once I add new rows to the gridviews?

Cheers!

Comment: Do you use UpdatePanel ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only case that this happens is when you use UpdatePanel.

Now when you use UpdatePanel, on each UpdatePanel the Dom is change and the javascript need re-initializations. Now in your case you add new lines, and you make ajax update, so you need to re-initialize the date picker.

This can be done from the functions that come with UpdatePanel as:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   // when dom is ready we initialize the UpdatePanel requests
   $(document).ready(function () {
       var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();    
       prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
       prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

       // Place here the first init of the DatePicker           
       $('.DateTimePicker').datepick({ dateFormat: 'dd MM yyyy' });
    });        

    function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
       // make unbind before update the dom, to avoid memory leaks.
       $('.DateTimePicker').unbind();
    }

    function EndRequest(sender, args) {
       // after update occur on UpdatePanel re-init the DatePicker
       $('.DateTimePicker').datepick({ dateFormat: 'dd MM yyyy' });
    }
</script>
```

Similar:
[Asp.Net UpdatePanel in Gridview Jquery DatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341623/asp-net-updatepanel-in-gridview-jquery-datepicker)
[Datepicker for dynamically created controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226774/datepicker-for-dynamically-created-controls)

Comment: thansk soooo much - you're right im using updatepanel. will make the changes as you suggest and see!

Comment: @viv_acious Be carefull, do not use your old javascript init of the datepicker, only this code I have write here.

Answer (score 0):

$(function () {

```
        $('.DateTimePicker').datepick({ dateFormat: 'dd MM yyyy' });
    });
```

It means it will hit once time. Try to use forEach function Like this:

```
$(function () {
        $('.DateTimePicker').each(function () {
            $(this).datepick({ dateFormat: 'dd MM yyyy' });
         });
        //$('.DateTimePicker').datepick({ dateFormat: 'dd MM yyyy' });
    });
```

Comment: This is not correct, the selector selects all controls as it is, and apply to all the datepick. The each function is a helper if you wish to make manipulation, but in this case you are not do anything.