# Updating an ajax model pop up in an update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have a page with an update panel, this page also has an ajax model popup. When I click some buttons I make some changes in code behind and then show the popup. For some reason when I click the button in the update panel no changes occur in the popup.

Debugging through the click I see that the changes are applied but the popup is not refreshed.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some code will help more. Some javascript need to re-initialize after every upatepane refresh. One example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227477/datepicker-not-appearing-after-adding-rows-to-editable-gridview/16227685#16227685

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register a post back trigger so that the popup is completely refreshed. This is of course if you want the page to post back, otherwise if you want those changes to be reflected in the popup you will need to use javascript.

example:
    asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="UploadTemplateImageButton"

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the panel visibility to false on page load.
ex: panel1.Visible=false;