# jquery datepicker on postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datepicker

i'm using a jquery datepicker and i'm facing the problem that when a postback is made the the datepicker disappears. I've tryed to reinitialize the datepicker on page load. 
Please advice, thanks in advance.
I tryed so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
pageLoad(); 
    SetValues();   
});
function pageLoad() {
        $("#calendar").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy' });
   }
```

Comment: You probably use UpdatePanel... correct ?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227477/datepicker-not-appearing-after-adding-rows-to-editable-gridview

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#calendar").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy' });
    }); ;

    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {
            $("#calendar").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy' });
        }
    };

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is correct logic.After postback you get new html with not initialize datepicker.Initialize date picker on page load is correct.

Comment: Then what is wrong and make the datepicker to disapper?

Comment: Where you call function pageLoad()